# Rollup Summary field value does not get changed on the code written

Tags: visualforce, pdf, roll-up-summary

Can any one help me on this ?RollUp Summary field can be multiplied in a visual force page.Based on the condition ,I need the value of the RollUp summary to get multipled (0.01) in wrapper class .

"Subtotal__c" and "Non_Pick_Total__c" are Roll up summary fields on Opportunity Object.They give the "Sum" of Opportunity Product aggregates on Extension Field.Extension(Extension=qty*1) is a Formula field data type as Currency on Opportunity Product.

The issue I'm having is that the "Extension" field value is getting calculated based on the formula field but it should get calculated as per the changes made in the visual force page and display (Extension = Qty*0.01) on the subtotal.

Condition :

If the product line for the product selected in opportunity items is ‘DIE’ make following changes .

1) unit price should change to $.01.

2)Unit price just change on the PDF display only and with extended amount which will be quantity times .01.

3)Subtotal__c=Non_Pick_Total__c

How do I achieve this?I shall appreciate your help.
VF CODE :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  renderAs="PDF" applyhtmltag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="InvoiceController">

     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" >
        <tr>
            <td class="header-heading">
                Ship Date:
            </td>
            <td class="header-data">
                <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText><br/>
            </td>
            <td class="header-heading">
                Special Instructions:
            </td>
            <td class="header-data">                
                <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Special_Instructions__c}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><f style="color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;"></f></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Customer_VAT_number__c}"></apex:outputText><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <table>
        <tr border="0">
            <td class="header-table-heading">CI Invoice Id</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Ship Date<b/></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-heading">Sales Order#</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-heading">Opportunity Name</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Order Date</td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-heading">Customer#</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Sys_createddate__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data">{!Opportunity.account.Ebs_Customer_number__c}</td>-->
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">LN</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Item</td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-heading">BinItemCode</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Item #<b/></td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">COO</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">ECCN #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">UOM</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Unit Price</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Quantity</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Extension</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading"></td>
            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left"  class="header-table-heading">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList}" var="line">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!if(line.pick==false, true, false)}">

        <tr>         
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.LineNumber}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.productname}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.BinItemCode}"></apex:outputText></td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">8541.40.2000</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EA</td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data">$1</td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data">$<apex:outputtext value="{!line.unitprice}"></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.quantity}"></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.extension}"></apex:outputtext></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left" class="header-table-data"><b>Scheduled Ship Date:</b>
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                <apex:param value="{!line.Scheduledshipdate}"/>
                        </apex:outputText> </td>
        </tr>
        </apex:outputPanel>    
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Gross Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Net Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Shipped Via</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Tracking #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Payment Terms</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Incoterms </td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Currency </td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Sub Total <br/>Shipping Charges</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-data" id="sub"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c}"></apex:outputText>
                                                   <br/><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText><br/></td>

        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList1}" var="line1">
        </apex:repeat>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Gross_Weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Net_weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipped_Via__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Bill_of_Lading__c}"> </apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">Net 30</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EXW</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">USD</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading"> Total Amount Due</td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c + opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Code :

```
    public with sharing class InvoiceController {
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList {get;set;}
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList1 {get;set;} 
           public list<string> address{get;set;}
           public string address1{get;set;}
           public string address2{get;set;}
           public string address3{get;set;}
           public string address4{get;set;}
           public string address5{get;set;}
           public string address6{get;set;}
           public string address7{get;set;}
           public String showaddressonVf{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
            public static wrapperClass tempObj2 ;

   //Added by sumit
               List<String> stringList ;
               public String all{get;set;}
           //------------
   public InvoiceController(){
   list<opportunity> op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c
   from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
    //opportunity op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
       //---------------------Added by sumit----------------------
       stringList= new List<String>(); 
       if(op.size()>0)
       if(op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=NULL && op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=''){
           List<String> stringList=(op[0].Shipment_Info__c).split(',');
               for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
               }

           all=all.remove('null');      
        }
      //------------------------------------------------------------
   }
       public Id OppId{get;set;}



       public InvoiceController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       oppId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
   }
               public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList (){
               wrapperClass tempObj;
               tempObj = new wrapperClass();

               List<wrapperClass> aReList = new List<wrapperClass>(); 
           List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           List<opportunity> Opp1=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid];
           //Opportunity opp1=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           //Opportunity Opp=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid ];
                          List<OpportunityLineItem> OPplineitem= [SELECT OpportunityId,Quantity,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name,Sys_total_Amount__c,LN__c,Extension__c,ListPrice
                          ,Pick__c,Schedule_Ship_date__c,Bin_Item_Code__c ,PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c,OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Subtotal__c,OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c
                           FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:oppId]; 
                          system.debug('HHHHHHHHHH'+OPplineitem.size());
                          tempObj2 =new wrapperClass();
                         // tempObj1.Subtotal=
                       for(integer i=0; i < OPplineitem.size(); i++)
                       {
                     tempObj = new wrapperClass();
                     tempObj.productname= OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                     tempObj.BinItemCode=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;
                     tempObj.quantity=OPplineitem[i].Quantity;
                     tempObj.totalamount=OPplineitem[i].Sys_total_Amount__c;
                    // tempObj.Subtotal =OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Subtotal__c;
                 //   tempObj.NonPickTotal=OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c;

                     //j=j+OPplineitem[i].Quantity * tempObj.unitprice;

                    // tempObj.productline=OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c;
                     //Add a conditional statement here


                 if(OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c=='DIE') 
                     {
                      tempObj.unitprice=0.01;
                      tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Quantity * tempObj.unitprice;
                      tempObj.productname=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;
                      //tempObj.Subtotal =j;
                      if(i==0){
                      tempObj2.Subtotal=tempobj.extension;
                     }
                     else{
                      tempObj2.Subtotal=tempObj2.Subtotal+tempObj.extension;
                       }

                    // tempObj1.Subtotal =tempObj1.Subtotal+tempObj.extension;
                     system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+tempObj2.Subtotal);

                    //tempObj.NonPickTotal=OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c*tempObj.unitprice;

                     }
                 else
                     {
                     tempObj.unitprice=1;
                     //tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c ;
                    }
                     tempobj.LineNumber=OPplineitem[i].LN__c;
                     tempobj.Pick= OPplineitem[i].Pick__c;
                     tempobj.ScheduledShipDate = Opplineitem[i].schedule_ship_date__c;

                     if(tempobj!=null){
                        aReList.add(tempObj);
                     }
                    }

           return aReList;


   }



       public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList1 (){
           wrapperClass tempObj1 ; 
           List<wrapperClass> aReList1 = new List<wrapperClass>();
                   List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId,Shipment_Info__c,
                    Shipping_Address_Line1__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line2__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line3__c,
                        Shipping_City__c,
                        Shipping_State_Province__c,
                        Shipping_Zipcode__c,
                        Shipping_Country__c  
                        from Opportunity where id=:oppid];
           for(integer i=0; i < opp.size(); i++)
           {
             tempObj1 = new wrapperClass();
             tempObj1.billingAddress= opp[i].Shipment_Info__c;
                               }
             aReList1.add(tempObj1);        

             /* Below code commented by Kiranmai as Shipment Info field is split into multiple fields

             //------- Added by Sumit-----------  
             stringList= new List<String>(); 

             if(aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL && aReList1[0].billingAddress!=''){
                List<String> stringList=(aReList1[0].billingAddress).split(',');
                for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
                }
             } */

             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line1__c + '<br/>';
             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c + '<br/>';
             } 

             if(opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + '<br/>';
             }  

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';
             }
            /* all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + ', '+opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + ' - ' + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';*/

             all=all.remove('null');

                /*-----------------------------------*/ 
      return aReList1;  
   }
           public class wrapperClass{
          // public String Item{get;private set;}
           public String productname{get; set;}
           public String BinItemCode{get;set;}
           public Decimal Quantity{get;set;}
           public Decimal totalamount{get;set;}
           public Decimal Subtotal{get;set;}
           public Decimal NonPickTotal{get;set;}                            
           public Decimal unitprice{get;set;}
           public date todaysdate{get;set;}
           public decimal extension{get;set;}
           public string LineNumber{get;set;}
           public string billingAddress{get;set;}
           public string splittedaddress{get;set;}
           public string productline{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
           public boolean Pick{get;set;}
           public date ScheduledShipDate{get;set;}
           public wrapperClass(){}                
       }


}
```

When i check in the Debug logs the value gets calculated but it does not get changed in the visual force page.
PFA SCreen Shot :
[image]
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "does not get changed in the visual force page"? How are you displaying these values on the page? Is the code you posted part of the initialization of the page or a result of some action?

Comment: @ CyberJus:Based on condition i have written a logic in the code.The logic works in condition for step 1 and 2 and fails at step 3.The code posted is a part of the logic written .

Comment: As you using a wrapper class for tempObj2, and are are you doing anything to that tempObj2.subtotal other than what you posted? Can you add a debug into your else condition to check how it is incrementing?

Comment: @CyberJus:i have  updated the complete code ,the tempObj2 is used for the logic

Comment: can you post your VF code so I can see those fields being used? As far as I can tell, since you using that wrapper class, any roll-up fields on the object should not matter - you are doing your own roll up.

Comment: @CyberJus:I have update the VF code.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: OK, so you are doing all of this custom calculation of the wrapped Product line, then make it 0.01, and then you are storing that value in tempObj2. But you are using the Opportunity value on your VF page. It does not appear that you are updating the lines or anything, so the Opportunity does not know anything about your custom calculation. You would have to use your tempObj2 values on the VF page or alter your object model to include that logic already in your rollups.

Comment: @ CyberJus:Can please let me know how to use tempobj2 in vf page or another alternate way to get the logic.I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to add a getter to tempObj in your controller:  public static wrapperClass tempObj2 {get; private set;} Then in your VF page just call that object and property {!tempObj2.Subtotal}

Comment: @CyberJus:I have added the getter to controller and in vf i have called the property as {!Opportunity.tempObj2.Subtotal__c} [<apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.tempObj2.Subtotal__c}"></apex:outputText>]but it throws an Error as :Invalid field tempObj2 for SObject Opportunity .Then i changed it as {!Opportunity.Subtotal__c} but there is no change in the o/p.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: @CyberJus:Thanks for your time and needful help.Its working .<apex:outputText value="{!tempObj2.Subtotal__c}"></apex:outputText>].The o/p  gets displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing the a custom calculation using an object in your controller, you need to make sure that object is the one being used on the page.

In this case the controller is doing a custom calculation using tempObj2 into the Subtotal property. The fix is to use {!tempObj2.Subtotal} on the Visualforce page.

Comment: :I have a visual force page created for 4 reports and has wizard controller .The logic is working fine at one report and gets failed for other report.For PickReport & PickReportUS :The condition is Subtotal__c=Non_Pick_Total__c(Rollup summary :Aggregrates the Extension,has a Criterias as "Pick is False" ) and for InvoiceReport&InvoiceReportUS:Subtotal__c=Pick_Total__c(Rollup summary :Aggregrates the Extension,has a Criterias as "Pick is True" ).

Comment: When i use the {!tempObj2.Subtotal} on the Visualforce page in place of "{!opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c}",It is displaying  the total value of extension instead of one value which is not picked .Similarly in case of Invoice report.Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is most likely caused by the use of a *formula* field. Can't you create a new field just for this? (since its not possible to overwrite a formula field)

Comment: :This formula field is linked  with other roll up summary field for the aggregration with their criterias.I tried changing the formula ,it works for one condition and the next condition gets failed.when i unchange the formula one conditions get failed and the other works .Any help very much appreciated.